# PHP heartbeat (cronjob tab)

Tags: php

I'm running a hearbeat file to dynamically add/remove cronjob commands from my admin dashboard.

I save the commands in a table like this:

```
+---------------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
| cronjob_id    | hour  | min  | command           | output        |
+---------------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
| 1             | *     | *    | /mail.php         | /mail.log     |
| 2             | 00    | 00   | /update.php       | /update.log   |
+---------------+-------+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

My heartbeat file:

```
/**
 * create a timeset
 */

$hour = date('H');

$minute = date('i');

/**
 * select all the commands
 */

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT hour,minute,command,output FROM cronjobs");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    include_once(ROOT.$row['command']);

    error_log("Command: ".$row['command']." executed\n",3,ROOT.$row['output']);

};

$stmt->close();
```

As you can see, the command **/mail.php** should be executed **every minute** and the command **/update.php** should be executed **every day at 00:00 (midnight)**. How can I code this in my heartbeat file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to add a date type `last_run` column to your table and then evaluate the hours & minutes since that time and execute if required and update the `last_run` column with the current datetime.

Use an existing library to evaluate the next time a task should be run like this one: https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

The following is untested code because I don't know the library but hopefully will get you closer to a solution:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (command_should_execute($row)) {
        include_once(ROOT.$row['command']);

        error_log(
           sprintf('Command: %s executed\n', $row['command']),
           3,
           ROOT.$row['output']
        );

        // UPDATE last_run COLUMN HERE
    }
};

function command_should_execute($commandArray)
{
    $cronExpression = $commandArray['minute'] . ' ' . $commandArray['hour'];
    $cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory($cronExpression);
    $nextRun = $cron
        ->getNextRunDate($commandArray['last_run'])
        ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return (strtotime($nextRun) < time());
}
```